# How to print data from a table in php?

Tags: php

How can I print d_name on browser? How to use for loop or any any other condition in this script for showing 5 d_name in  `<ul><li>` tags ?

I want output like this

> user5
>
> user4
>
> user3
>
> user2
>
> user1

My config file is:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 ?> 



 session_start();

 if(!isset($_SESSION['****']) and (!$_SESSION['auth'])==*)
 {
    header('Location:index.php');
  }

  include 'config.php';
  $list="select d_name from donated order by d_id desc limit 5;";

  $data=mysqli_query($con,$list);

  if ($uresult= mysqli_query($con,$list))
     {
       //counting rows
       $urows= mysqli_num_rows($uresult);
     }  
 echo $urows;

$info = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
   print_r($info);
}
```

OR

```
  while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
       echo $info['d_name'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to do it:

```
$data = mysqli_query($con,$list)or die(mysql_error());

$resultTable = ‘<table>’;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
    {
        $resultTable .= '<tr><td>' . $row['d_name'] . '</td></tr>';
    }

$resultTable .= ‘</table>’;

echo $resultTable;
```